# Image Header not passed from OOP to index.php

Tags: php, functional-programming, http-headers

When i am calling my image resize function within the page it runs smoothly and resize my image but when i include it in my index page and call it from index.php then header not sends and it generate a long text like this

```
=>GIF87aªç–ƒx‡dWtaZffeCA<ÕÆ¶CBBŠVNfXT;BC§‡w²¤™wxw¹†g‡˜–êÆ©C;:x‡‡ˆˆ…
```

and so on. Please resolve my issue or i will create this function directly in index.php?

This my function.php page code below

```
class img{
function resize()

{

// File and new size
$filename = 'upload/845.gif';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
ob_start();

echo header("Content-Type: image/gif");

ob_end_clean();


// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromgif($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
@imagegif($thumb);
imagedestroy($thumb);
}
}
```

This is my index.php code below

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
include("function.php");
$img_resize=new img;
$img_resize->resize();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with OOP?

Comment: it generate thumbnail image....

Comment: Is there other content you intend to display at the same time, or do you just want to display the image alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a separate file to output the image and then load it in an `<img>` tag.

```
// image.php
include("function.php");
$img_resize=new img;
$img_resize->resize();

// HTML file
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="image.php" />
  </body>
</html>
```

That's if you're trying to include the image in an HTML file. If you're just trying to output the image, as others have hinted, then you don't need any HTML at all you just want to output the image.

Comment: but how will i send this image name which i got from database in while loop

Comment: Try using `<img src="image.php?name=<?php echo $name; ?>" />` in your loop, and then in your `img` class you could use `$_GET['name']` to determine the image you want to load.

Comment: Oka.....once again cheers solved completely.....send it through image.php?id=imagepath then image.php execute further.....:-D

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the header info after you've entered the `body` tag.

I suggest removing the HTML altogether if all you are displaying is an image.

Answer (score -1):

```
ob_start();  
echo header("Content-Type: image/gif");  
ob_end_clean();
```

try just like this

```
header("Content-Type: image/gif");
```